# How to restrict viewers from downloading until they subscribe to my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I have some pdf's link on my site. I want whenever someone tries to download those pdf's, a popup will pop for a subscription. Now the main thing is I don't want users to cut this popup unless they subscribe to my website.
Pdf's to be allowed to download only after subscription process.

Note : There is no login or signup option on the website. It is just a normal surfable website with some pdf's link.

Answer (score -1):

This plugin should do what you're looking for:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-to-download/

I've used it before and it worked fine back then.